# How come new Date(0L) doesn't return zero date

Tags: java, datetime

```
Date date = new Date(0L);
```

Shouldn't it give me a zero date? Like 00/00/0000? Gives me **Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969**

Comment: The date 00/00/0000 does not exist (the entire year '0' never existed). If software pretends it exists that's a bug.

Comment: It all started with the Big Bang..

Comment: That's just a theory (hi Kaley!). And that would have been around 1/1/13,700,000,000 BC (I might be a few days off)

Comment: There was no 0 day, 0 month or 0 year. ;)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Per the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), this constructor on `Date` uses an offset from baseline time:

> Allocates a Date object and
>   initializes it to represent the
>   specified number of milliseconds since
>   the standard base time known as "the
>   epoch", namely January 1, 1970,
>   00:00:00 GMT.

Presumably you are on EST, hence the result.

As an aside, I would not expect the result you noted to be produced by any conceivable `Date` manipulation, since that's not even a valid date (month and day = 0).

Answer (score 5):

From the Java API:

> Date(long date): Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 1):

The time is milliseconds since the epoch.

The epoch is 1/1/1970 GMT.

Answer (score 1):

Because that constructor creates the object initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Answer (score 0):

Java dates, and most computer implementation of dates, are stored as milliseconds of seconds starting from what's called the epoch. That is 1 January, 1970. Java date is represented as milliseconds since epoch. and 0 milliseconds since epoch is the epoch itself. And that's why you get that value.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

First moment of 1970 in UTC:

```
Instant.EPOCH.toString()
```

> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

And the same moment as seen in New York region:

```
Instant.EPOCH.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ).toString()
```

> 1969-12-31T19:00-05:00[America/New_York]

## Details

The other Answers are correct: The epoch reference is first moment of 1970 in UTC while your time zone is 5 hours *behind* UTC. Here's updated info.

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

The epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z is defined as a constant, `Instant.EPOCH`.

```
Instant.EPOCH.toString()
```

> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

To see that same moment in another time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. You can think of it as: “ZonedDateTime = Instant + ZoneId”.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.EPOCH.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 1969-12-31T19:00-05:00[America/New_York]

The result is a time-of-day five hours earlier, on last day of previous year. This `ZonedDateTime` represents the same moment, the same simultaneous point on the timeline, but a different wall-clock time.

That same moment in India is five and a half hours *ahead* of UTC rather than *behind*.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.EPOCH.atZone( z ) ;

    System.out.println(zdt );
```

> zdt.toString(): 1970-01-01T05:30+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).